# Criando uma string de data padrão MySQL de um Java Date

Tags: java, mysql

Eu preciso passar uma string nesse formato: "yyyy-mm-dd+HH:mm:ss" (onde o "+" deve ser um espaço) para um webservice a partir de um objeto Date do Java. De que forma consigo fazer isso?

Comment: O que já tentou? Qual a origem do dado?

Comment: java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf =
                new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmm:ss");

Comment: o seu passar seria salvar no banco Mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode fazer com o `SimpleDateFormat`, porem se você estiver passando a data a ser formatada no modo "dd/MM/yyyy" e está tentando passar pra um webservice, o `SimpleDateFormat` não vai conseguir formatar. aconselho a troca o "/" pelo "-".

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o SimpleDateFormat para fazer isso.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String formatedDate = dateFormat.format( date );
```

Você pode ler mais sobre aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html